# HTML anchor tag with Javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick, anchor

On using Google I found that they are using onclick events in anchor tags.

In **more** option in google header part, it looks like normal a tag, but onclicking it doesn't get redirected but opened a menu. Normally when using

```
<a href='more.php' onclick='show_more_menu()'>More >>></a>
```

It usually goes to 'more.php' without firing `show_more_menu()`, but I have show a menu in that page itself. How to do like **google**?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

If your onclick function returns false the default browser behaviour is cancelled. As such:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com' onclick='return check()'>check</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function check()
{
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Either way, whether google does it or not isn't of much importance. It's cleaner to bind your onclick functions within javascript - this way you separate your HTML from other code.

Comment: 1. To be more sure, use a # in href="#" and do the necessary things within the javascript. It is safe to click on that link with # href; the page does leave/reload url.

Comment: Follow the above advice with caution, as HTML5 rules explicitly state that `href="#"` is supposed to navigate to the top of the page. You can simply add the `href` attibute without content, and get the click behaviour. Assinging `#` as url for real pages (Rather than single-page 100% height apps) is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Just a note, in the same way you bind a CSS class to an element and then specify the detailed styles in a separate CSS file, it is perfectly good to bind an inline event handler *function* to an element, and then specify the detailed implementation of that function in a separate JS file.  Your HTML file is where you declare the structure, appearance, as well as behavior of your webpage.  The detailed implementations reside elsewhere.  That's the kind of separation you really want.

Comment: can the function chack pass variable? eg check('123')

Answer (score 65):

You can even try below option:

```
<a href="javascript:show_more_menu();">More >>></a>
```

Comment: Warning: If the function returns any explicit value (ex: `return null;`, but not `return;`), this will have unintended consequences in some browsers, such as FireFox. The page will have all content replaced with the returned value in string format (ex: `[object Object]`).

Answer (score 61):

From what I understand you do not want to redirect when the link is clicked.

You can do:

```
<a href='javascript:;' onclick='show_more_menu();'>More ></a>
```

Comment: This is helpful when you don't want the href to point anywhere.

Comment: It is cool and It works but jquery throws an error "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: javascript:;"

Comment: I am using jQuery version 1.10.2, and I do not get the syntax error that @TheOddCoder experienced.

Answer (score 9):

Use following code to show menu instead go to href addres

```js
function show_more_menu(e) {
  if( !confirm(`Go to ${e.target.href} ?`) ) e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href='more.php' onclick="show_more_menu(event)"> More >>> </a>
```

Comment: Is there a spec somewhere that spells out why `event` magically works, but `evt` does not?

Comment: @JamesIrwin in my code I not use `event` - I think you can create new question in stack-overflow and ask

Answer (score 2):

One more solution that prevents default action even if the `javascript` function returns any value.

```
<a href="www.any-website.com" onclick='functionToRun();return false;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Link to work
<a href="#" onClick={this.setActiveTab}>
      ...View Full List
                    </a>
  setActiveTab = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can recreate an anchor tag with a div adding `role="link"`, this doesn't have the `href` but at the same time it should be fine from a SEO point of view

```
<div tabindex="0" role="link" aria-label="Example Link" onclick="show_more_menu()">
  Click to navigate
</div>
```