# Including both href and onclick to HTML <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

If I have this element:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com" onClick="javascript.function();">Item</a>
```

How can I make both `href` and `onClick` work, preferably with `onClick` running first?

Comment: Check this **[Set A tag link in HTML using JavaScript](https://debug.to/3093/how-to-replace-string-in-current-url-with-javascript)**

Comment: This one may help, It works for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7347854/14437411

Comment: @Mohamed what is your link about, does it help?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You already have what you need, with a minor syntax change:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="return theFunction();">Item</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function theFunction () {
        // return true or false, depending on whether you want to allow the `href` property to follow through or not
    }
</script>
```

The default behavior of the `<a>` tag's `onclick` and `href` properties is to execute the `onclick`, then follow the `href` as long as the `onclick` doesn't return `false`, canceling the event (or the event hasn't been prevented)

Comment: Is there also a way to do this with an element.addEventListener function?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, until I put `href="#"` there instead of a real URL.

Comment: I'm using laravel framework, so in my blade view I included this, It is not working, have anyone tried this with laravel?

Comment: This solution is not working if i have any action method called in mvc controller in href. Can somebody please help ?

Comment: Does it make sense to first have `onclick` and then `href`? Probably to have a counter, popup etc with onclick and then going to the link?

Answer (score 12):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com). You need to capture the `click` event and then go on to the website.

```js
$("#myHref").on('click', function() {
  alert("inside onclick");
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myHref">Click me</a>
```

Comment: i won't use any javascript framework. but thank you for your answer

Comment: Above is not an actual link. It cannot be opened in a new tab and is a very bad practice. If something can be opened in a new tab (has na url) always add a meaningful `href` attribute.

Answer (score 8):

To achieve this use following html:

```html
<a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="make(event)">Item</a>

<script>
    function make(e) {
        // ...  your function code
        // e.preventDefault();   // use this to NOT go to href site
    }
</script>
```

Here is [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/qe9g8s5h/14/).

Comment: This works for me in Chrome however Safari seems to run the function but not open the href...any sugestions?

Comment: @Ben I made test on fiddle without JS - only pure html: `<a href="http://example.com" >Item</a>` and in Chrome i see some message to allow page to run this link (alert at the end of chrome url bar). In safari in console I see warrning: [blocked] The page at https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/ was not allowed to display insecure content from http://example.com/ - so probably this is some security issue (only on fiddle ? )

Answer (score 6):

No jQuery needed.

[Some people say using `onclick` is bad practice...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

This example uses pure browser javascript. By default, it appears that the click handler will evaluate before the navigation, so you can cancel the navigation and do your own if you wish.

```html
<a id="myButton" href="http://google.com">Click me!</a>
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        document.querySelector("#myButton").addEventListener("click", e => {
            alert("Clicked!");
            // Can also cancel the event and manually navigate
            // e.preventDefault();
            // window.location = e.target.href;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This works by overriding the default behaviour, and there's nothing to say it's a bad practice. This is the approach I used as it removes the onClick (having href and onClick was confusing tbh), so thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<button>` instead. In general, you should only use a hyperlink for navigation to a real URL.

We can style a button to look like an anchor element.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#onclick_events

Anchor elements are often abused as fake buttons by setting their href to # or javascript:void(0) to prevent the page from refreshing, then listening for their click events .

These bogus href values cause unexpected behavior when copying/dragging links, opening links in a new tab/window, bookmarking, or when JavaScript is loading, errors, or is disabled. They also convey incorrect semantics to assistive technologies, like screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. However, preventing the default behavior of `a href` and then 'manually' following the link, did work.

The code sample would be:

```
<a href="https://example.com" onClick="myFunction(event)">Link</a>
<script>
function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // do your thing here
    window.location.href = event.currentTarget.href;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -5):

Use `ng-click` in place of `onclick`. and its as simple as that:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com" ng-click="return theFunction();">Item</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function theFunction () {
    // return true or false, depending on whether you want to allow 
    // the`href` property to follow through or not
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Only in AngularJS