# Change link href depending on users connection offline or online

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jqueryUI/jquerymobile for an WebApp. There is a button which should check if the user is connected to the internet or not. Wether he is or not the href of the link should change. I tried the following but it does not work. Any ideas why? It opens the link to http://test.com every time, no matter if online or offline.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnClick () {
        if ('onLine' in navigator) {
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                window.location = "http://test.com/";
            }
            else {
                window.location = "test.html";
            }
        }
        else {
            alert ("Your browser does not support the onLine property.");
        }
    }

</script>

<li class="ui-corner-none nav2"><a href="http://test.com/" onClick="OnClick ()">Link</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the logics behind it - but my guess is that the click on the "link" will be initiated first (aka the browser follows the link first) and than the `OnClick` event fires (which will do nothing because it isn't on the same page anymore).

Read more about it: [JavaScript function in href vs. onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070760/javascript-function-in-href-vs-onclick)

My fix would be to check upon pageload if you are connected to the internet and change the 'href' attribute of the link.

```
$(function() {
    if ('onLine' in navigator) {
        if (navigator.onLine) {
            $("li.nav2 a").attr("href", "http://test.com/")
        }
        else {
            $("li.nav2 a").attr("href", "test.html")
        }
    }
    else {
        alert ("Your browser does not support the onLine property.");
    }
});
```

another quicker fix would be

```
<li class="ui-corner-none nav2"><a href="http://test.com/" onClick="return OnClick ()">Link</a></li>
```

See: [HTML tag <a> want to add both href and onclick working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working)

Comment: Thanks but it does nor work entirely. The test.com website works, even if i change the href in the a tag . But if i switch to offline the browser wants to open test.com again and not test.html