# HTML Tag <a> with both href and onclick and AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, perl, tags

I want to have both href and onclick working and I found a solution here:
[HTML tag <a> want to add both href and onclick working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working)

In myFunction, I make an AJAX Request calling a perl component.

It works fine when I put the Javascript call in href, but not when in onclick. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed this solution neither jQuery, so can you please help.

```
// AJAX Request doesn't work
<a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="myFunction();">Item</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction () {
        var xmlHttp = getXMLHttpObject();
        xmlHttp.open('GET', 'perl.m', true);                
        return true;
    }
</script>

// AJAX Request ok
<a href="javascript: myFunction('www.mysite.com')">Item</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction (url) {
        var xmlHttp = getXMLHttpObject();
        xmlHttp.open('GET', 'perl.m', true);
        window.location.href = goto_url;                
    }
</script>

perl.m:
<%init>
    warn "perl.m";
    ... update ...
</%init>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please carefully follow the tutorial. It states that you must enter the javascript like this (with return keyword).

`<a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="return theFunction();">Item</a>`

Besides that you should always type in a URL (like http://stackoverflow.com).

Please let me know if this supports you.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. The new site can be called by click but although by clicking on "New Tab" in the context menue, and then without my Ajax Request. I googled a lot but didn't find a solution yet. It would be great if you could help again.

Comment: I am happy that my first answer helped you. Do you mind explaining your further question more detailed? Does the opening via context menu (I assume FireFox) work?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com" onclick="myFunction(event);">Item</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var xmlHttp = getXMLHttpObject();
        xmlHttp.open('GET', 'perl.m', true);                
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Because you have `href` attr with url, so it will go to url and your ajax is not affected. 
`e.preventDefault()` is your solution here.

Comment: Thank you. I tried e.preventDefault(), the AJAX call works with it. But the URL in href isn't called any more, although the function returns true.

Comment: Of course that the Url in Href will not access, because you have called Ajax. If you want to access with href attr , please use window.location.href = <href url>;