# How to run onClick and href both in an Anchor tag (&lt;a&gt;)

Tags: javascript, html

On clicking executing href but not javascript function please help me out of this problem.Thanks in advance ...

On clicking the link, it's executing the href  but not executing javascript.

Any ideas how to achieve the same?

My code is:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <img id="first-image-{{this.id}}" src="./img/image-bg.png">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
      <a id="first-camera-{{this.id}}" onclick=" javascript:currentImgViewId()" href="#dialogPage" data-transition="pop"><img src="./img/camera.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And on click is:

```
function currentImgViewId() {
  alert("hahs");
}
```

Comment: Just use onclick="currentImgViewId()"

Comment: I DID THAT earlier but was not working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML tag <a> want to add both href and onclick working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
onclick="javascript:currentImgViewId()"
```

by this:

```
onclick="currentImgViewId()"
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qm37d73p/)

The `javascript:` is intended to be used as a link/typed in the address bar for the browser to execute the following codes as javascript code relative to the page.

Comment: @TulikaKansal Make sure your javascript code is define *before* the HTML code is defined, and NOT at the bottom of your page :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return true` from the  `currentImgViewId()`

```
function currentImgViewId() (){
  alert('blah');
  return true;

}
```

`return true`  proceed to process the `href` after your function returns and go to the proper anchor

`return false` means that it would not processed

if you don't return anything it will return `undefined`.