# Save advert click to database using PHP, then open link

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress widget that shows and advert. When the advert is clicked I want to record the clicks with some detail.

The database table is already created and entries can be saved correctly using the function `f1_add_advert_click($advert_id)` in `save-advert-click.php`, which resides in the same directory as the Widget's PHP that I want to call it from (the plugin's root directory).

Requirements:

- link will be on a piece of text, just a plain a href
- a visitor should see the target link when he hovers his cursor over the link, not appended by a parameter for the next page
- no 'middle' page that registers the click then redirects onto the target page. Just straight from the origin to the target.
- secure: the advert ID is passed on to the f1_add_advert_click function and then inserted into the database. I would like to be sure that it's  the correct ID (not something a visitor could change).
- there can be multiple instances of this Widget on a page

I have seen and tried a lot of examples on Stackoverflow, but either I don't get it or the situation there is different from mine. Would gladly appreciate a well commented code example that works in my situation. Please be aware that I am not a seasoned programmer, especially 'green' when it comes to JavaScript and jQuery.

From what I have read on the web I think I should be using AJAX to first register the click, then send the browser to the target page. Not sure if I have to use onclick or not, based on the bottom answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working).

Have put in about four hours so far on this part. Now asking for help. Not much code to show, because I deleted everything that didn't work.

This is what I have currently got within the widget function of the plugin (left out the regular php showing title and so on):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: './wp-content/plugins/facilitaire-advert-widget/save-advert-click.php',
        data:{action:'call_this'},
        success:function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Followed by the link and the click action

```
<p><a href="" onclick="myAjax()" class="deletebtn">Link of Advert</a>
```

Then these are my contents for save-advert-click.php

```
// check for action signal
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
    f1_add_advert_click ();
}


/**
 * Records a click event in the database
 */
function f1_add_advert_click ()
{
    $advert_id = random_int(1,300); // change to $clicked_advert_id later
    $user_ip = get_user_ip();

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'f1_advert_clicks';

    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'advert_id'=> $advert_id,
        'user_agent'=> $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        'ip_address'=> $user_ip
        ),
        array(
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Get user IP
 */
function get_user_ip()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if ( filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) ) {
        $ip = $client;
    } elseif ( filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) ) {
        $ip = $forward;
    } else {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**
Thanks to @mplungjan's suggestion I updated my code to the following, working code. Please note some differences with @mplungjan's code, because I had to make some adjustments to make it work in WordPress.

contents of bottom part of `show-advert.php`

```
<script>
jQuery(function() { 
    jQuery(".advertLink").on("click",function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the link unless it has a target _blank or similar
        var href = this.href;
        var id= <?php echo $advert_id; ?>;
        jQuery.post("<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/plugins/facilitaire-advert-widget/save-advert-click.php",
             { "action":"register_click", "advert_id":id },
             function() {
                 location=href;
             }
         );
    });
});
</script>

<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" id="advert1" class="advertLink">Link of Advert</a><br />

<?php
```

Then in the top part of `save-advert-click.php` I have

```
<?php

// check for action signal
if($_POST['action'] == 'register_click') {
    f1_add_advert_click( $_POST["advert_id"] );
}

/**
 * Records a click event in the database
 */
function f1_add_advert_click ( $advert_id )
{
    $user_ip = get_user_ip();

    // need to load WordPress to be able to access the database
    define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
    require_once( '../../../wp-load.php' ); // localhost needs this, production can have require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'f1_advert_clicks';

    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'advert_id'=> $advert_id,
        'user_agent'=> $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        'ip_address'=> $user_ip
        ),
        array(
            '%d',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: What have you done thus far? Please provide some code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts. If closed, the question can be re-opened after you have posted some more html and php

Comment: We would highly recommend you visit the help pages as mentioned by @mplungjan :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I went over the suggested pages and making edits to my original post now.

Comment: Here is the [markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Hint: indent the full code 4 spaces from the left by selecting it and hitting the {} button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do something like

```
$(function() { 
  $(".advertLink").on("click",function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link unless it has a target _blank or similar
    var href = this.href;
    var id=this.id; // or $(this).data("advertid") if you have data-advertid="advert1" on the link
    $.post("./wp-content/plugins/facilitaire-advert-widget/save-advert-click.php",
       { "action":"call_this", "advert_ID":id },
       function() {
         location=href; // or window.open
       }
     );
  });
});
```

using

```
<a href="url_to_load" id="advert1" class="advertLink">Link of Advert</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan!

I have used your code example. Don't see entries in the db yet. I suppose it has to do with the way I pick up the variable in `save-advert-click.php`.

It now has
`f1_add_advert_click($parameter);

'function f1_add_advert_click ($ad_id)
{
 $advert_id = $ad_id;`
then the original rest.

Comment: Yeah I did not use your parameters - I'll have a look in an hour

Comment: Updated to use your parameters exactly

Comment: Thanks again @mplungjan I have changed my code but did not get it to work yet. Can you please have another look?

Comment: Any errors in the console (F12) can you call the post using a simple form? Why not take the ID from the link instead of using a random thing?
I am off to bed

Comment: WOW! Finally did it! Updated code above now works!<br />Found an error in my code with the ID. That's sorted now. Then there was an error in the console with the $ referring to jQuery. Since jQuery in WP runs in noConflict mode, I had to replace it with jQuery. Then I found out that because `save-advert-click.php` lives outside of PHP I had to get wp-load involved. Added `get_home_url()` to make sure the link to `save-advert-click.php` worked from all pages, not just home. Ad finally had to learn how to get variables that are posted to a page with `$_POST["variable"]`. Thanks again!<br />