# Add delay for href (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to add a delay time for an href

```
 href = {{ page( ) }}
```

I want to add a delay time before redirecting to the next page .

Comment: It's not task for PHP/Laravel, but JS. You're looking for `setTimeout`.

Comment: yes , i want to use setTimeout but i don't know the good syntax to use it on laravel .

Comment: Nothing to do with laravel. Study basics of JS syntax. In HTML you need to work with `onclick` attribute instead of `href`.

Comment: see this [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) and make it on [href click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working)

Answer (score 3):

There is no option for it in Laravel.
You can do it with JS:

```
<a id="theLink" href = {{ page( ) }}>LINK</a>


<script>
  $('#theLink').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
          window.location.href = self.href;
      }, 2000);
  });
```