# Inserting a big JavaScript in a html onlick Tag

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a big `JavaScript` Code in a html file like 
`<script>CODE</script>`

Now, this whole paragraph should only execute if the user clicks on a button (or something like that)

for example
`<button id="MyButton" onclick= ???>MyButton</Button>`

Thanks Guys :)

Comment: A simple googling would solve this issue.

Comment: i tried it. But I only find solutions for inserting functions and thats to much work for the hole code

Comment: just have the whole code insite a function then call said function when you click the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML tag <a> want to add both href and onclick working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working)

Comment: That's why **JavaScript** has `functions` and not just lines of code. Wrap it in `function fun{CODE}` to get it `onClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function, and specify that function in your button onclick.

```
<script>
function doSomething() {
CODE
}
</script>
<button id="MyButton" onclick="doSomething()">MyButton</button>
```