# How do i make onClick and href work together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `a` element which has his own href and it works perfectly. The problem is that besides an `href` element i want to make an `onClick` function, but when i do so, the `href` is ignored:

```
<li><a href="#someSectionOfThePage" onClick={someFunction}>GO TO SECTION</a></li>
```

Using this syntax, the `someFunction` runs, but i'm not being redirected to `#someSectionOfThePage`.

Comment: Why would you do that though? What is the main idea behind that?

Comment: Please include `someFunction` code.

Comment: To achieve what you want you might wanna try using the function on the <li onclick="Your Function"> element and leave <a href=""> ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML tag <a> want to add both href and onclick working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867558/html-tag-a-want-to-add-both-href-and-onclick-working)

Comment: What does `someFunction` do? Can you add the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try to add a `click event` handler for `li` and make sure `li` and anchor tag `a` takes the same `width`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<li onClick={someFunction}>
   <a href="#someSectionOfThePage">GO TO SECTION</a>
</li>
```

When you click the `<li>` it will execute the function... and when you click the `<a>` it will process the `href`. Since you'll be clicking this element, both will work the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `href` present in the a tag is not going to work because of the `onClick` event. After clicking the element, instead of redirecting you to the section of the page, it executes `someFunction()`.  You may try adding 
    `location.href = "#someSectionOfThePage"`
to `someFunction()` which will do the work of `href`.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not advisable but if you still want to use both then this might do the trick:

```
someFunction= ()=>{
  window.location.href("#someSectionOfThePage");
  //do your onClick stuff here
};

<li>
  <span onClick={this.someFunction}>GO TO SECTION</span>
</li>
```

Hope this helps!!