# How to change variable value when click function is called?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the check value from `false` to `true` whenever I click on the a link. So far I've not found any suggestions on how to do this

```js
<a href="#" class="click"></a>
<a href="#" class="click">Click Me</a>

let check = false;

document.querySelectorAll('.click').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    check = true;
  });
});

console.log(check);
```

Comment: Use the onClick event https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick https://stackoverflow.com/a/14867603/495157

Comment: This works as it is - move the `console.log(check)` inside the eventListener

Comment: @Light thanks but I want to change value in global.

Comment: You are changing it in the global scope

Comment: @David your `console.log(check)` gets executed right after you define your click event. It's not being called after you click or any other time after. If you look at your `check` variable *after* you've clicked, you'll find it's been set. You could add another click link that checks the value and shows it to the user in HTML or an alert if you want to test it out

Comment: @lurker Can you please write code for me? Thanks

Comment: @David I've done this for you in my answer - The button with the text 'Console.log(check)' console.logs the value of check from the global scope

Comment: @Light I checked it but its not worked..

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @David you already know how to write the code. You've obviously written code to set the variable on a click. (I assume you wrote it, did you?) You just write a little bit of similar code that reads the variable. You can call `alert` for a quick check to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Your `console.log()` is being executed after you assign the onclick event, not after it is *called* - So the only thing you log is the value of checked at the very beginning of your script

I've moved the `console.log()` inside the function, and also added a separate button so you can confirm that the value of check has changed in the global scope

```js
let check = false;

document.querySelectorAll('.click').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   check = true;
   
   // Check value has changed
   console.log(check);
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="click"></a>
<a href="#" class="click">Click Me</a>

<br>
<button style="margin-top: 10px" onclick="console.log(check);">Console.log(check)</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution already works, you just have to move your `console.log(check)` to print the new value

```js
let check = false;

document.querySelectorAll('.click').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {

   check = true;
   // print the new value
   console.log(check);
  });
});


console.log(check);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="click"></a>
<a href="#" class="click">Click Me</a>
```