# Button inside hyperlink div

Tags: javascript, html

I have an  element with an hyperlink. Inside the  are also buttons, which should trigger their button actions, without triggering the hyperlink.

Demo code:

```
<a href="element.html">
 <div class="element_card">
   This is an card for an element with an hyperlink over the card.
    <button type="button" onclick="like_element()">
      Like the element but do not trigger the hyperlink.
    </button>        
 </div>
</a>
```

How can I disable the hyperlink for the button or cancel the event, so that the button area ia only triggering the onclick function for the button but not the hyperlink.

Comment: you will need javascript, but what have you tried until now, do you have some JS code? is it not working?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Buttons can't be descendants of anchors

Comment: @j08691 why not? A block level anchor is akin to a div. OP just would need to stop the propagation when handling the button's click event.

Comment: @GetSet I didn't make the rules

Comment: Technically it will work, but doesn't follow the html spec. A workaround is to use a wrapping `div` with your `a` and `button` tags as children, then use css positioning to make the `button`s appear as if they are inside the `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent further propagation of the current event in the bubbling phases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 4):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` to block the click from travelling up the chain.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

The default behavior of the `<a>` tag's `onclick` and `href` properties is to execute the onclick, then follow the `href` as long as the `onclick` doesn't return false, canceling the event (or the event hasn't been prevented)
See if this works for you.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14867603/11623848)

```
<a href="element.html">
 <div class="element_card">
   This is an card for an element with an hyperlink over the card.
    <button type="button" onclick=" return like_element()">
      Like the element but do not trigger the hyperlink.
    </button>        
 </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

using this inside href javascript:void(0)

```js
function like_element(){
  console.log('working....!')
}
```

```css
.element_card{
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
 <div class="element_card">
   This is an card for an element with an hyperlink over the card.
    <button type="button" onclick=" return like_element()">
      Like the element but do not trigger the hyperlink.
    </button>        
 </div>
</a>
```