# Call to the function printTable does not work on the label a

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

***The call to the printTable function does not work on the a tag, I add it through onclick ();
am I coding wrong?, what would my mistake be.
Could you please help me to identify where I am failing***

[image]

```
<a title='Imprimir' data-toggle="tooltip"  class='waves-effect waves-light' id="boton"><i class='fa fa-print'></i></a>
```

Here you should open a pdf

```
<script>
     
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#boton").click(function() {
        var cliente= $('#NombreCliente').text();
        var capitalp=$(this).parents("tr").find("td")[5].innerHTML;
        var abono=$(this).parents("tr").find("td")[4].innerHTML;
        var totalPago = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[1].innerHTML;
        var iva = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[2].innerHTML;
        var interes = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[3].innerHTML;

        var HTML ="<div style='position: relative; '><img src='<?= base_url() ?>plantilla/images/logo' style='position: absolute; background-size: 100% 100%; filter:alpha(opacity=25); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5); opacity:.25; left:100px; top: -10px;'></div>";
         HTML+="<img src='<?= base_url()?>plantilla/images/logo.png'  width='100'><div class='row text-center'><h1>PRESTAMAS DINERO AL INSTANTE S.A.</h1> </p><p>Comprobante de pago</p></div>";
        HTML+= '<table  class="table table-bordered">';
          HTML+= '<tr class="tr tr1">';
            HTML+= '<td><strong>Cliente</strong> </td>';
           HTML+= ' <td>'+cliente+'</td>';
          HTML+= '</tr>';
          HTML+= '<tr class="tr tr1">';
            HTML+= '<td><strong>Por</strong> </td>';
            HTML+= '<td>'+totalPago+'</td>';
          HTML+= '</tr>';
          HTML+= '<tr class="tr tr1">';
            HTML+= '<td><strong>Abono capital</strong> </td>';
            HTML+= '<td> '+abono+'</td>';
          HTML+= '</tr>';
          HTML+= '<tr class="tr tr1">';
            HTML+= '<td><strong>Intereses</strong> </td>';
           HTML+= '<td>'+interes +'</td>';
          HTML+= '</tr>';
          HTML+= '<tr class="tr tr1">';
           HTML+= '<td><strong>Iva</strong> </td>';
            HTML+= '<td>'+iva +'</td>';
          HTML+= '</tr>';
          HTML+= '<tr class="tr tr1">';
           HTML+= '<td><strong>Capital pendiente</strong> </td>';
            HTML+= '<td>'+capitalp +'</td>';
          HTML+= '</tr>';
          HTML+= '<tr class="tr tr1">';
           HTML+= '<td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px;" align="center"><strong>CON SU ESFUERZO Y NUESTRO APOYO PROSPERARÁ SU NEGOCIO</strong> </td>';
          HTML+= '</tr>';
        HTML+= '</table>';
        var pantalla=window.open(' ','popimpr');
        pantalla.document.write('<link href="<?= base_url() ?>plantilla/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />');
        pantalla.document.write(HTML+"<p>Contabilidad</p><br>"+HTML+"<p>Cliente</p>");
        pantalla.document.close();
        self.location ="<?= base_url()?>Creditos";
      pantalla.focus();
      pantalla.onload = function() {
        pantalla.print();
        pantalla.close();
      };
       //$(".ocultarImprimir").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

***Here you should open a pdf window***

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` tag generally has a default behaviour when you click on it.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14867603/16408272), try to add an `href="#"`:

```
<a title='Imprimir' data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="imprimirTabla()" class='waves-effect waves-light ver boton' href="#"><i class='fa fa-print'></i></a>
```

Or you could try to add a `return` inside the `onclick`:

```
<a title='Imprimir' data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="return imprimirTabla();" class='waves-effect waves-light ver boton'><i class='fa fa-print'></i></a>
```

Or try to add the `onclick` event to the print `<i>` icon:

```
<a title='Imprimir' data-toggle="tooltip" class='waves-effect waves-light ver boton' href="#"><i class='fa fa-print' onclick="imprimirTabla()"></i></a>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and write a brief summary of the content of the link you provide. Remember that such content may no longer be available at later. Read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

my mistake was not declaring in the tag id = "boton"

```
<a title='Imprimir' data-toggle="tooltip" class='waves-effect waves-light' id="boton"><i class='fa fa-print'></i>Imprimir</a>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#boton").click(function() {
        var cliente= $('#NombreCliente').text();
        var capitalp=$(this).parents("tr").find("td")[5].innerHTML;
        var abono=$(this).parents("tr").find("td")[4].innerHTML;
        var totalPago = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[1].innerHTML;
        var iva = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[2].innerHTML;
        var interes = $(this).parents("tr").find("td")[3].innerHTML;
```