# html: execute function when link clicked, get alert and then redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html, function, redirect, alert

What's the best way to combine two strings

String 1:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunc();" onclick="alert('myFunc executed')">Click here</a>
```

and
String 2:

```
<a href="http://google.com">click here</a>
```

so that:
myFunc() executed;
alert appears;
once alert is clicked, the page is being redirected to `http://google.com`

I'm asking about the most correct way to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Refer the link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347786/html-anchor-tag-with-javascript-onclick-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert('myFunc executed');myFunc();window.location='http://google.com'">Click here</a>`

explanation :

`javascript:void(0)` Is for u to see a link.

Comment: What if the target is a new window, but through javascript it's blocked by popup.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="myFunc(); alert('myFunc executed'); return true">click here</a>
```

Comment: I just wanted to trigger google analytics event when user clicks on any link. For my use case this approach was quite handy.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is very "obtrusive" JavaScript.  Nowadays, folks tend to recommend an [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach.

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://google.com" data-message="myFunc executed">Click Here</a>
```

Note that there is no JavaScript in the HTML.

Then, in your script module, you can initialize as below (I use jQuery for brevity):

```
$("#myLink").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
        message = $(this).attr("data-message");
    myFunc();
    alert(message);
    window.location.href = href;
});
```

This technique leaves your HTML clean and allows you to perform multiple actions on the click event.

Finally, if you are not familiar with the concept of modules in JavaScript, take a look at Douglas Crockford's book [JavaScript, The Good Parts](http://books.google.com/books/about/JavaScript_The_Good_Parts.html?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C).

Comment: small change.. it's `$("#myLink").click(function(){` :)

Comment: @Yashrajsinh Jadeja, Good catch. I edited to show your correction.  Thanks.

Comment: This opens the link in same window... I would like the target be new window but not blocked by popup