# wait till anchor tag onclick function response is true

Tags: javascript, html, fullpage.js

I searched a lot for this but no solution yet.
Here is my code.

```
<a href="#second" onclick="return slide();">second </a>
```

javscript:

```
function slide() 
{
    //do something
    //There are slides on #second. I am expecting sliding should start before 
    //#second visible in viewport but right now #second is visible and then it starts sliding. 
    $.fn.fullpage.moveTo(section1, 0);
    return true;
}
```

I am using fullpage.js for sliding the slides.

When I click on second I am expecting function to return value and then href to execute. Is it possible or not?

If not is there any solution for it?

Comment: That is what that code does. What do you think it doesn't?

Comment: If "do something" is an asynchronous task, then the slide function won't block the click event. Could you provide more information on what happens in the function?

Comment: There are slides on #second. I am expecting sliding should start before #second visible in viewport but right now #second is visible and then it starts sliding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html: execute function when link clicked, get alert and then redirect to another page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829351/html-execute-function-when-link-clicked-get-alert-and-then-redirect-to-another)

Comment: @GuillaumeDeroy It's not duplicate. I can't use location.replace function as I don't want to refresh my page

Comment: Could you please provide sample code?

Comment: If you don't want the default click action to fire, you should use `return false` or `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Well then please explain _what_ you want to do. You are talking about slides, so I would assume you are using some kind of JS slider plugin/script … but you completely failed to mention which one.

Comment: @cmbuckley I want default click action to fire but only after function returns true value

Comment: It sounds like you want #second to be invisible at the time the slide() function is called, but that it is already visible, and that is a problem. Is that what troubles you? I assume that "#second" is literally a reference to an anchor in your DOM. What DOM is at #second and how is it styled?

Comment: @CBroe I edited question and mentioned the plugin I am using.

Comment: @Robinlikethebird: this is exactly my problem. #second contains html code for horizontal slides that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try like this.
Take one dummy a-tag for 'Second'. If on click of `dummy-second` the `function slide()` returns true, than by using jquery's `trigger` event you can fire a click event to activate Slider

You can hide and show `slidersecond` & `dummysecond` these a-tags depending on your requirement in `slide()` function

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return slide();" id="dummysecond">second </a>
<a href="#second" style="display: none" id="slidersecond" >second </a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
  function slide()
  {
     //do something
    //There are slides on #second. I am expecting sliding should start before 
    //#second visible in viewport but right now #second is visible and then it starts sliding.

    var something = true;
    //If something is true
    if (something) {
      //trigger your slider
      $("#slidersecond").trigger('click');
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element with `id="second"` needs to be styled to not show.

There are many different css properties that could make it not show, and styling could be done statically on the `id="second"` element using the `style` attribute, or in a style sheet with `#second` as the selector, or dynamically using jQuery's `style()` method.

I don't know enough about the fullpage plug-in to make a more precise recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

May be these should be help you.

```
//Create a anchor tag
<a href="https://javagunjan.wordpress.com/">Click Me</a>
```

Using JQuery check When Click on link.

```
$("a").click(function(){
     alert("Hello World !");
});
```

It's should be work proper see  [Demo FIDDLE here. CLICK Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/higunjan/mg3e1qzn/)

**OR**

```
<a href="https://javagunjan.wordpress.com/" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</a>


function myFunction(){
   alert("hi");
}
```