# href links not working with onclick events in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, onclick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ref() {
    location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
</script>

<a target="_blank" href="/somepage.html" onclick="javascript:ref()">CLICK ME</a>
```

In Chrome, FF and IE, clicking the link will open Google in the current window and open somepage.html in a new tab/window

But in Safari it will just open Google in the current window and nothing else.

How can I make Safari replicate the other browsers?

Comment: Not probably a solution, but a comment: it's just `onclick="ref()"` without `javascript:`

Comment: thanks, edited, didnt make any difference but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML anchor tag with Javascript onclick event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347786/html-anchor-tag-with-javascript-onclick-event)

Comment: Using the developers tool in Safari, is there any error in the console?

Comment: Nope, no errors or warnings at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`location.href` will only change the URL of the current window. In order to open a new tab or window, its better to use `window.open`. I tested it in Safari specifically (and Chrome) and it is working in both browsers.

```
<a href="/somepage.html" onclick="javascript:ref()">CLICK ME</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function ref() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');
}
</script>
```

The way you had it written, somepage.html will open in a new tab and the current page will redirect to google. If you want it that way just switch the URLs around like so:

```
<a href="www.google.com" onclick="javascript:ref()">CLICK ME</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function ref() {
    window.open('/somepage.html', '_blank');
}
</script>
```

A side note, I found out that Safari allows user to handle how they want windows opening, whether it be a new window or a tab, and unfortunately we do not have any control over that.

Comment: thanks, but that wouldn't also open `/somepage.html`. I need to open a new tab and change the URL of the original tab all with 1 click.

Comment: @MikeMeade sorry about that. I updated my answer above. That should work as you need.